# <form> element in React does not work like i expect it to

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, input

I'm trying to create a form element where the user can enter input. 
If I insert the form element directly, everything works fine when typing the letters.
If I insert the form element via `AddForm` component, I can only type one letter and have to click into the field again to enter the next letter.

Why is that?

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const App = () => {

    const [newName, setName] = useState("")
    const [newNumber, setNumber] = useState("")

    const handleName = (event) => {
        setName(event.target.value)
    }

    //doesn't work the way I expect it to
    const AddForm = () => {
        return (
            <form>
                name: <input value={newName} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} />
                <div><button type="submit">add</button></div>
            </form>

        )
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <AddForm />
            //does work
            <form>
                name: <input value={newName} onChange={handleName} />
                <div><button type="submit">add</button></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AddForm` function is created on every render so from `React` perspective `AddForm` is a different component causing the related DOM elements getting recreated which makes it look like the input element lost its focus.

Move `AddForm` outside of `App` (and pass required data into it through props).

---

> why is AddForm not re-rendered when it is outside App and why are the  elements not re-rendered when they are directly inside App?

React updates the DOM in an effective way, only changing things that are different but it's not perfect. It compares components with `===` and if they don't match, the whole tree is removed.

Since you recreate `AddForm` on every render, current `AddFrom` is not equal to previous `AddFrom`. This makes React remove the `form` associated with `AddForm` and create another one in its place.

When you put `AddForm` outside, current `AddForm` is equal to previous `AddForm` so React just compares the return values of previous and current `AddForm` and updates the DOM associated with `AddForm` (that is, just adds another char to the input field)

Comment: Thank you. I restructured it the way you wrote it and it worked.

But I still don't understand two things 100 percent.
 - when does the rendering happen? (evertime i type something?)
-  why is AddForm not re-rendered when it is outside App and why are the <form> elements not re-rendered when they are directly inside App? Why is the <form> Elemtn only re-rendered when it is inside AddForm and AddForm is inside App?

Comment: @dasLicht I've added further explanations to my answer.